# Unable to append a sheet using OpenXml with F# (FSharp)

Tags: f#, openxml

The CreateSpreadsheetWorkbook example method from the OpenXml documentation does translate directly to F#. The problem seems to be the Append method of the Sheets object. The code executes without error, but the resulting xlsx file is missing the inner Xml which should have been appended, and the file is unreadable by Excel. I suspect the problem stems from the conversion of functional F# structures into a System.Collections type, but I do not have direct evidence for this.

I have run similar code in C# and VB.NET (i.e. the documentation example) and it executes perfectly and creates a readable, complete xlsx file.

I know that I could deal with the XML directly, but I would like to understand the nature of the mismatch between F# and OpenXml. Any suggestions?

The code is almost directly from the example:

```
namespace OpenXmlLib
open System
open DocumentFormat
open DocumentFormat.OpenXml
open DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging 
open DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet

module OpenXmlXL = 
   // this function overwrites an existing file without warning!
   let CreateSpreadsheetWorkbook (filepath: string) = 
      // Create a spreadsheet document by supplying the filepath.
      // By default, AutoSave = true, Editable = true, and Type = xlsx.
      let spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filepath, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook)
      // Add a WorkbookPart to the document.
      let workbookpart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart()
      workbookpart.Workbook <- new Workbook()

      // Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart.
      let worksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>()
      worksheetPart.Worksheet <- new Worksheet(new SheetData())

      // Add Sheets to the Workbook.
      let sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets()) 

      // Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
      let sheet = new Sheet() 
      sheet.Id <-  stringValue(spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart))
      //Console.WriteLine(sheet.Id.Value)

      sheet.SheetId <-  UInt32Value(1u)
      // Console.WriteLine(sheet.SheetId.Value)

      sheet.Name <-  StringValue("TestSheet")
      //Console.WriteLine(sheet.Name.Value)


      sheets.Append (sheet)

     // Console.WriteLine("Sheets: {0}", sheets.InnerXml.ToString())

      workbookpart.Workbook.Save()


      spreadsheetDocument.Close()
```

The sheet is created, but empty:

sheet.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  <x:worksheet xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" />

workbook.xml:
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <x:workbook xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
- <x:sheets>
  <x:sheet name="TestSheet" sheetId="1" r:id="R263eb6f245a2497e" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" /> 
  </x:sheets>
  </x:workbook>
```

Comment: Can you post your code? What exactly is contained in the xlsx when you unzip it? Is the sheet created but empty? Are any refences added to it?

Comment: Looks like you're using the example code from this MSDN page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff478153.aspx . I really doubt this is a problem with F# -- your code looks right, but you might have found an erroneous example on MSDN. See if you can use the example code verbatim in a C# project, do you get different results?

Comment: Thanks to kvb. The cast worked. I had tried this on the Sheets and the Sheet object, but it never occurred to me that the SheetData object was suspect. Thanks again.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is very subtle, and is in your calls to the `Worksheet` constructor and the `Sheets.Append` method.  Both of these methods are overloaded, and can take either a `seq<OpenXmlElement>` or any number of individual `OpenXmlElement`s (via a `[<System.ParamArray>]`/`params` array).  The twist is that the `OpenXmlElement` type itself implements the `seq<OpenXmlElement>` interface.

In C#, when you call `new Worksheet(new SheetData())`, the compiler's overload resolution picks the second of the overloads, implicitly creating a one-element array containing the `SheetData` value.  However, in F#, since the `SheetData` class implements `IEnumerable<OpenXmlElement>`, the first overload is chosen, which creates a new `WorkSheet` by enumerating the *contents* of the `SheetData`, which is not what you want.

To fix this, you need to set up your calls so that they use the other overload (first example below) or explicitly create a singleton sequence (second example below):

```
worksheetPart.Worksheet <- new Worksheet(new SheetData() :> OpenXmlElement)
...
sheets.Append([sheet :> OpenXmlElement])
```

Comment: +1: Thanks. This really helped me out, I was following the example on MSDN for DocumentFormat.OpenXml and just couldn't see what was wrong!